# Best approach to upload large files to Rails app using React/electron as front-end

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, electron

I would like to know what is the best approach to implement the upload of large files to a Rails app but the front-end isn't in Rails it is in React/electron. Besides, I can't use S3 or any kind of cloud storage the files goes directly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 things.

1. backend service that handles the file uploads via API
2. frontend library to call to the backend via API

**For the backend** you could use something like [paperclip](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip), [carrierwave](https://rubygems.org/gems/carrierwave) or [active storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/active_storage_overview.html)

**For the frontend** I like to use [Uppy](https://uppy.io/) which has a very user-friendly UI and is compatible with react

Here is a guide that could be useful to you https://gorails.com/episodes/uppy-with-active-storage